# Vault and Consul: Vault storage not showing up in Consul UI

Tags: kubernetes, consul, hashicorp-vault, key-value-store

I am trying to set up Vault on my Kubernetes cluster with Consul as the storage. I have followed [this official tutorial](https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/getting-started-k8s/minikube) which uses Helm charts to install Consul and Vault on Kubernetes and sets up Vault to use Consul as storage. Installation has been successfull as can be seen here:

```
NAME                                                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
hashicorp-consul-connect-injector-webhook-deployment-84589dtg6k   1/1     Running   0          43m
hashicorp-consul-server-0                                         1/1     Running   0          43m
hashicorp-consul-rscsm                                            1/1     Running   0          43m
hashicorp-consul-jdtbj                                            1/1     Running   0          43m
hashicorp-consul-x4hmc                                            1/1     Running   0          43m
vault-agent-injector-5945fb98b5-78gw8                             1/1     Running   0          34m
vault-0                                                           1/1     Running   0          34m
```

After that, I registered Vault as a service manually by running

`consul services register vault.json`

with `vault.json` being:

> {"service": {"name": "vault", "tags": ["vault-tag"], "port": 8200}}

Now, In Consul's dashboard UI, I am able to see Vault in services with a green tick which shows health checks are being performed correctly but when I create key values in Vault I can't see any storage being created in the key-value menu of the UI. I would appreciate it if someone could help me understand what's wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is not mentioned in the tutorial, Consul is only used as storage when Vault is installed in High Availability mode. I recreated my cluster and re-installed Vault in this mode by running:

```
helm install --name vault \
    --set='server.ha.enabled=true' \
    https://github.com/hashicorp/vault-helm/archive/v0.3.0.tar.gz
```

Now, Vault is automatically registered as a service in Consul and its storage shows up in Consul's Key/Value menu.